# Scaling of commands in the editor are wrong on external qhd monitor

Tags: texstudio

I Just installed newest versions of TeXstudio and MiKTeX on new surface pro 4 with windows 10.

things work fine, until I drag TeXstudio from the surface's screen, to my external monitor. See the picture, as you can see it's unusable like that.
I have no Idea what to even search for to fix it, Does anyone know a solution?

Extra info:
The external screen is running on 100 % scale while the surface is running on 200 %. The surfaces resolution is 2736x1824 (recommended) while the external monitor is running on 2560×1440.

Thanks :)
[image: Left screen is surface's screen, where it would show just fine, left screen is on external monitor]

Comment: Under `Configure TeXstudio` -> `Editor`, there is an option for line spacing. Does increasing that help? If the buttons are too small because of the higher resolution, there is a scaling option under `GUI scaling` as well.

Comment: Hello. sadly not. The lines do get wider apart, but it doesn't fix the mess, It just looks the same but with more space between the lines. In addition to this, the active section which is selected (with the light blue background color) gets Drastically smaller than the rest.

Comment: Try `Configure TeXstudio` -> `Adv. Editors` -> `Workarounds` -> `Disable cache of rendered lines`? p.s. This is a known issue and a perfect solution is not available yet, I think. https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1506/

Comment: Troy, Thank you! This worked.
For anyone else finding this, You have to to tick "Show Advanced Options" under configuration to find the workarounds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ps. This is a known issue/bug and a perfect solution is not available yet, I think. See the [post on Sourceforge](http://www.sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1506).

To get around this, there is an option under:

> <kbd>Configure TeXstudio</kbd> -> <kbd>Adv. Editors</kbd> -> <kbd>Hacks/Workarounds</kbd> -> <kbd>Disable cache of rendered lines</kbd>
>
> (Activate this option).

You need to check the <kbd>Show Advanced Options</kbd> to get access to the <kbd>Adv. Editors</kbd> tab.